# Glitch Booting Linux with Spike?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, riscv

I used Spike to boot linux using the riscv tools but the linux boot sequence seems to stop at Bootconsole[early0] disabled.

I tried adding kernel command line root=/dev/vda ro console=ttyS0 but didn't work. The same console settings works in QEMU. Also checked the .config file for the line CONFIG_HVC_RISCV_SBI=y. It was there. Still coulnd't get past it.

Tried with Linux kernel version 4.19 to 5.2. No luck. Am I doing something wrong here?

Steps I followed:

Compiled linux with Riscv toolchain
compiled riscv-pk with ../configure --host=riscv64-unknown-elf --with-payload= [path to vmlinux]
used "Spike bbl" to start spike image.

Please let me know if any more info is required.

Sorry, noob here.

Attaching terminal output

```
bbl loader
OF: fdt: Ignoring memory range 0x80000000 - 0x80200000
Linux version 4.19.59 (root@AsusFX504) (gcc version 8.2.0 (GCC)) #2 SMP Sat Jul 20 05:11:32 IST 2019
bootconsole [early0] enabled
initrd not found or empty - disabling initrd
Zone ranges:
  DMA32    [mem 0x0000000080200000-0x00000000ffffffff]
  Normal   empty
Movable zone start for each node
Early memory node ranges
  node   0: [mem 0x0000000080200000-0x00000000ffffffff]
Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000080200000-0x00000000ffffffff]
software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0xfa3fe000-0xfe3fe000] (64MB)
elf_hwcap is 0x112d
percpu: Embedded 17 pages/cpu s29912 r8192 d31528 u69632
Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 516615
Kernel command line: 
Dentry cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
Sorting __ex_table...
Memory: 1988760K/2095104K available (5468K kernel code, 329K rwdata, 1751K rodata, 193K init, 806K bss, 106344K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
rcu:    RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=8 to nr_cpu_ids=1.
rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=1
NR_IRQS: 0, nr_irqs: 0, preallocated irqs: 0
clocksource: riscv_clocksource: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x24e6a1710, max_idle_ns: 440795202120 ns
Console: colour dummy device 80x25
console [tty0] enabled
bootconsole [early0] disabled
```

Comment: To see what’s there, you may add `keep_bootcon` to the kernel command line.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because ***Virtual Terminal*** is enabled in your linux `config`. Disabling ***Virtual Terminal*** might solve your issue.

In Linux **make menuconfig**  go to :-

Location:

- -> **Device Drivers**
- -> **Character devices**

and Disble **Virtual terminal**  .

```
Symbol: VT [=y]    n                                                                                                                                                                                 
Type  : bool                                                                                                                                                                                          
Prompt: Virtual terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously, the reason is that VT is enabled so kernel has a dummy VT framebuffer that simply goes nowhere, but you don't have to disable it. `console=ttyS0` will also not work, since SPIKE doesn't emulate it. Note that this won't work on the HiFive Unleashed, either, since serial terminals there are ttySIF0 and ttySIF1. What you want is `console=hvc0` and SPIKE will be able to continue from there, e.g. in your kernel .config:

```
CONFIG_CMDLINE_BOOL=y
CONFIG_CMDLINE="earlyprintk console=hvc0"
CONFIG_CMDLINE_FORCE=y
```